# Handling spaces in value with Python configparser

Tags: python

I'm currently working on a program that reads a file path from a config.ini file, to set a download directory to download pdf files to. Reading the file path from the config file works, but only if the path doesn't contain any spaces. The configparser documentation seems to suggest that spaces in values shouldn't be an issue, so I'm admittedly stumped right now. Placing doubles quotes or single quotes on the file path doesn't seem to help either.

config.ini's content:

```
[PATH]
download = C:/Users/censor/Downloads/Test Test
```

(censor is just a replacement for my real username, which doesn't have any spaces in it)

code:

```
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('config.ini', encoding='utf-8')

download_directory = config['PATH']['download']
print(download_directory)
```

output:

`C:/Users/censor/Downloads/Test`

Comment: I can't reproduce this at all. Are you sure you've saved the .ini file? Are you sure you're looking at the entire output?

Comment: same here, works fine.

Comment: If you run `with open('config.ini', encoding='utf-8') as f: print(f.read())` does the output match the content of your file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, and turns out I'm an idiot: I was editing the wrong .ini file... I had my config file saved in two locations, one with my python files, and one with my pyinstaller bundled .exe file. That was a stupid mistake on my end, but thanks for all the replies!

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this – this self-contained example works just fine (and so does using an external file):

```
import configparser
import io

sio = io.StringIO("""
[PATH]
download = C:/Users/censor/Downloads/Test Test
""")

config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read_file(sio)
print(dict(config['PATH']))
```

The output is

```
{'download': 'C:/Users/censor/Downloads/Test Test'}
```

just as you'd expect.